# GAS Copy Data to another Spreadsheet with currency and percent format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a block of code that copies data from one spreadsheet to another using the moveTo() function. The data consists of both $ and %, but that formatting is not being copied over to the 2nd sheet.

Is there anyway on the second sheet to "hard set" the format? Or is there a better way for me to do this?

NOTE** For whatever reason this block of code worked perfect on the old sheets, but stopped when I moved to the new sheet.

```
//Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getRange('B3:B9');
  var EndInv = ss.getRange('B11:B15');
  var Theoretical = ss.getRange('B17:B21');
  var Purchases = costReportPurchases.getRange('D12:D16');

//get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var EndInvRange = EndInv.getA1Notation();
  var TheoreticalRange = Theoretical.getA1Notation();
  var PurchasesRange = Purchases.getA1Notation();

//get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var EndInvData = EndInv.getValues();
  var TheoreticalData = Theoretical.getValues();
  var PurchasesData = Purchases.getValues();

//Makes the move to the second sheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxx'); // tss = target spreadsheet - Snap Shot
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('CompanySnapShot'); // ts = target sheet
  var cedarvilleCOGS = ts.getRange('F55:F61'); //Sets range on Snap Shot
  var cedarvilleEndInv = ts.getRange('F64:F68'); //Sets range on Snap Shot
  var cedarvilleTheoretical = ts.getRange('F93:F97'); //Sets range on Snap Shot
  var cedarvillePurchases = ts.getRange('F107:F111'); //Sets range on Snap Shot
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData).moveTo(cedarvilleCOGS);
  ts.getRange(EndInvRange).setValues(EndInvData).moveTo(cedarvilleEndInv);
  ts.getRange(TheoreticalRange).setValues(TheoreticalData).moveTo(cedarvilleTheoretical);
  ts.getRange(PurchasesRange).setValues(PurchasesData).moveTo(cedarvillePurchases);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the answer by calling the method `setNumberFormats()`

```
//This is for % based numbers
var formatFoodPercentPWSouth = [["00.00%","00.00%","00.00%","00.00%","00.00%","00.00%","00.00%",]];
  var rangeFoodPercentPWSouth = CompanySnapShot.getRange("B75:H75");
  rangeFoodPercentPWSouth.setNumberFormats(formatFoodPercentPWSouth);

//This is for $ based numbers
var formatLiquorDollarsEndingInventorySouth = [["$00,000.00","$00,000.00","$00,000.00","$00,000.00","$00,000.00","$00,000.00","$00,000.00",]];
 var rangeLiquorDollarEndingInventorySouth = CompanySnapShot.getRange("B79:H79");
 rangeLiquorDollarEndingInventorySouth.setNumberFormats(formatLiquorDollarsEndingInventorySouth);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same issue, I used `copyFormatToRange` after writing the values.

Have a read of this. 
[Google app guide to copyFormatToRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

as an example.

```
 ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData).moveTo(cedarvilleCOGS);
 srange.copyFormatToRange(CompanySnapShot,6,6,55,61);
```

That should (I hope copy the formating form the source range. and apply it to the destination.

I've not tested the above code yet,

You could also look at using NamedRanges and then setting the formatting after the data is written.

Comment: I feel this like should work, but it's not. Ughh.

How would I go about setting the format after the data is copied? That certainly would do the trick

Comment: Did you add
 `srange.copyFormatToRange(CompanySnapShot,6,6,55,61);`
After the line
`ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData).moveTo(cedarvilleCOGS);`

Comment: Yes, but srange isn't defined. I tried playing around with it but couldn't get it to work.

I got the example from the docs to work but only inside the same spreadsheet. When I try to send it to another via sheet id I get the error "Cannot convert Range to (class)"

Comment: Sorry, it should be `SRange` 
SR uppercase
IT could also be your source range is a column and target range a row.
are you able to share a sample of the sheets?

Comment: Our Domain is locked from Sharing.

After I changed to SR, it now hangs on "CompanySnapShot"

    SRange.copyFormatToRange(CompanySnapShot,6,6,55,61);

Error 
"Cannot convert Spreadsheet to (class)."